# Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, build-tools

How do I make this error stop please help me cause I have been trying to run my flutter app for a while now after it was infected by a virus
Whenever i try to run my flutter app it gives me this error

```
CreateProcessW failed 193
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt.EXE 
dump xmltree D:\flutter\MyApps\ohms3\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
```

accompanying with other errors

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung Galaxy S10 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.16.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_cropper-1.3.1\android\src\main\java\vn\hunghd\flutter\plugins\imagecropper\FileUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:9: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
import android.os.AsyncTask;
                 ^
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask in android.os has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        ^
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    ^
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:123: warning: [deprecation] doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        ^
  where Params,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:121: warning: [deprecation] AsyncTask() in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                                         ^
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:128: warning: [deprecation] onPostExecute(Result) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value) {
                     ^
  where Result is a type-variable:
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\sharedpreferences\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:131: warning: [deprecation] execute(Params...) in AsyncTask has been deprecated
    }.execute();
     ^
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
7 warnings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_flutter-0.3.24\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\FlutterWebView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
CreateProcessW failed 193
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\aapt.EXE dump xmltree D:\flutter\MyApps\ohms3\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
```

Please i have checked other solutions but none is working for me is there something i can do cause i really need to finish my production app for someone